# Why is the for loop not iterating over each item in the list?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, user-defined-functions

The for loop only iterates over the first item in the list. The code functions properly when i use a "print" statement instead of "return" however it outputs a "None" alongside the desired output. Not sure how to make the code work using the return function.

Current code -

```
def func(num) :
    for x in num:
        return "*"*x




list1 = [3,9,5,2]
print(func(list1))
```

Comment: what is your desired output? and for starter don't write `return` inside for loop

Comment: you probably need `return ["*"*x for x in num]`

Comment: `return` causes the entire function to exit immediately, in this case after the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that return is going to exit the function right away with the value following it when the keyword return is executed. So as the for loop starts, the first time it iterates, you return the value and right away and the function exits. If you want to return the list completely or the value in the list, you should make the function return a list of numbers or maybe make a string that concatenates all the value and then return the string after the for loop has iterated all the way.

Answer (score 0):

`return` exits a function, meaning you break out of the loop in the first iteration.

If you want a function to "return" several values, you can use yield (making the function a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator)):

```
def func(num):
    for x in num:
        yield "*" * x

list1 = [3, 9, 5, 2]
for result in func(list1):
    print(result)
```

As you can see, you then have to iterate over the result of the function call.